# Is there any way to tweak or modify AFP to increase transfer speed?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, mac-mini, file-sharing, afp

I have a Mac Mini, MacBook Pro and Synology DS213 connected to a gigabit switch via cat6 cables. When I enable AFP on the DS213, I get ~60mbpsUP and ~700mbpsDOWN when accessing it from Mac Mini and MBP. I also get the same speeds when both Mac Mini and MBP access each other. When I turn off AFP on the DS213, and use SMB, I get ~300mbpsUP ~350mbpsDOWN when accessing it from the Mac Mini and MBP.

When I view a Wireshark capture from Mac Mini --> DS213, there are MANY "request tickles" and "FPwriteExt request(s)" during the AFP ~60mbps uploads.

Is there any way to improve AFP upload (write) performance?